# Resetting an In-Memory database in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB for persisting Spring Batch Metadata tables.
I have successfully implemented it by providing 2 datasources in my Spring Batch application !

All I am concerned is that the in-memory database can grow infinitely if the spring batch is always up and executing jobs !

I want to clear the database tables or reset the in-memory database before the start of my first job !

Kindly help me implement that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box utility provided in Spring batch/Boot. If you really need to truncate spring batch meta data tables, you have to do it manually.

Probably, you could define a separate job to do that manually at set intervals or you could add a separate step to clear out the meta data tables in your first batch job.

Comment: `you could define a separate job to do that manually at set intervals` I would also do it that way.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah that I know where to place the clearing call or how to initiate the clearing process.
Was looking for the exact code for clearing the HSQLDB tables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something before or after a job you need to implement a JobListener and add the desired DAO logic to the beforeJob() method.

How ever I don't think you want to do that, or for that matter use an in memory database for Spring Batch.   Those tables contain all the job and audit tracking data which you will want to have when you get support calls or people asking about records they think were lost, or had some problem.   If you don't have that job or audit data you will not be able to track down what happened and when.

public class JobResultListener implements JobExecutionListener {

```
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    someDao.clearBatchTables();
}

public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The data in the HSQLDB database is in schemas. You can DROP the schemas, which drops all the tables.

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE
```

Alternatively you can TRUNCATE the schemas, which keeps the tables but deletes the data in them.

```
TRUNCTATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AND COMMIT NO CHECK
```

If you drop the PUBLIC schema, it will be recreated as an empty schema. See the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_truncate_statement